# openGL - issue when getting data via socket in glutTimerFunc

Tags: c++, sockets, opengl, glut

I am using UDP socket to send data to my openGL application. the openGL app should listent to the UDP socket in the `glutTimerFunc` callback and update the view according to the received data.

my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowSize(600, 600);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutCreateWindow("test");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);    
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutTimerFunc(1000, listenToUDP, 0); // here!

    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

my glutTimerFunc callback, which listens to the UDP socket:

```
void listenToUDP(int = 0)
{
    int sockfd,n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
    socklen_t len;
    char mesg[1000];

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);
    bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));


    len = sizeof(cliaddr);
    printf("1");

    // here is the problem !!
    n = recvfrom(sockfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len); 

    printf("2");
    sendto(sockfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesg[n] = 0;
    printf("Received the following:\n");
    printf("%s",mesg);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");

    map<string, float> info = parseInfo(mesg);
    scaleX += info.find("x") -> second;
    printf("%f", scaleX);

    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(1000, listenToUDP, 0);
}
```

***when the first time I sent data to the application, it worked great***. it waited for the data on the line I marked, and it printed everything and updated the view accordingly after I sent data  to it.

However, ***it didn't work since the second time I sent data to it***. it would print "1" but never print "2", which means it suspended on the line I marked. of course it would not update the view, either.

I am sure the UDP listener works well if it's independent(run it with an infinite loop), so I guess it's a problem related to the `glutTimerFun`. However, I totally have no idea.

my question is:

1) what's the reason for this behavior?

2) how can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you recreating the socket every time?

Comment: I have to set many global variables if I don't create it every time. I don't want to create too many global variables. is there any better solution?

Comment: You don't have to set global data, since it is c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use & operator to get the address of function.

```
glutTimerFunc(1000, &listenToUDP, 0);
```

Please also remember to close the socket after using it every time:

```
close(sockfd);
```